# align divs horizontally inside another div

Tags: html

I am trying to append divs horizontally to an existing div. I am giving `float:left` property and added `overflow-x:auto`. I expect that parent div width < than width of all child divs then horizontal scroll should appear.But its not working as desired.
I want all divs in horizontal line 
Div1 Div2 Div1 Div2 Div1 Div2 Div1 Div2

Here is code

```
<div style="overflow-x:auto;width:100px;height:100px">     
    <div style="background-color:lavender;float:left">
      Div1       
    </div>
    <div  style="background-color:lavenderblush;float:left">
          Div2
    </div>
     <div style="background-color:lavender;float:left">
      Div1       
    </div>
    <div  style="background-color:lavenderblush;float:left">
          Div2
    </div>
     <div style="background-color:lavender;float:left">
      Div1       
    </div>
    <div  style="background-color:lavenderblush;float:left">
          Div2
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `float: left;`, use `display: inline-block;` on the inner containers, then add

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

to the outer container.

https://jsfiddle.net/9c1mrcoe/3/

Edit: In the fiddle, I have now cleaned all the inline styles and used css classes instead.

Answer (score 0):

just replace those `float: left` with this - `display: table-cell`
JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/5qpqakL6/